# What documents are required for "proof of assets" for Canada Visitor Visa

Tags: visas, canada, proof-provenance-of-funds

A "Proof of assets or business" document is required under "Proof of Means of Financial Support" for a Canada visitor visa. This is an additional requirement on top of bank statements.

Does "Proof of assets" include showing houses, mutual funds, and other investments? I have a house and equity investment, including mutual funds as an asset. I want to provide all the documents that show ties in my country to make a strong case for a visitor visa application.

Does the above asset declaration justifiable under "Proof of assets"?

Comment: Proof of assets doesn’t seem to appear in the list of documents published here: https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/supporting-documents.html

Answer (score 1):

The most normal "proof of assets" are statement from a bank or other investment accounts. The intention is to show that you have enough money to be able to afford the trip you are going to make. If you can do that by just providing financial statements that will be fine. If you can't showing you own a house will not help much, as hardly anybody will sell their house in order to take a vacation.

Proving you own a house does establish ties to your country - for that reason it may be worth including a deed, but the precise value is probably not important.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Since I don't have a travel history, I want to make a strong case for my visitor visa on top of financial statements. For that, I would like to provide all the proofs that can be help full to show that I will return back to my home. Also, I have dependent parents in my home country but I don't know how to provide such details on paper.